# Are there any open source code-oriented textfield Cocoa classes?

Tags: cocoa, textfield

I'm aware of the [SubEthaEdit Engine](http://www.codingmonkeys.de/subethaengine/) that Panic uses in Coda, but are there any decent open source Cocoa classes for presenting a code-oriented text field editor?

I'd like to provide a feature in my Mac app where users can edit code using syntax highlighting and perhaps autocompletion, and I'd prefer not to re-invent the wheel or spend all my time on this one aspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I have no direct experience with this code, it does fit your bill - code editing and syntax highlighting:

Meet [Fraise](https://github.com/jfmoy/Fraise/)!